# Defragment pagefile on windows 10 or diagnose PerfectDisk failure

Tags: windows-10, boot, defragment

I've recently had to change pagefile size thanks to changing hardware specs and, naturally, new part of pagefile is fragmented from original file. I've used to defragment it with PerfectDisk until upgrade to Windows 10, but even the latest version seems to not work now.

It does load at boot time and displays "optimizing disk C:" message, but instead of showing progress percentage and file list after that, as it used to do, it immediately exists and continues usual Windows boot process without defragmenting anything.

1. Is there a verbose log of process to see why exactly PD's boot defrag didn't work?
2. Is there any other alternatives to optimize pagefile short of booting from other medium?

Comment: This could occur if there was insufficient unfragmented disk space for the new pagefile. Try a normal defrag first.

Comment: don't care about this, you don't access the pagefile too much to see a diff. if you have a lot of pagefile usage, install more RAM to make Windows faster and reduce the activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler)'s boot time defrag, or Microsoft's own (and old) [PageDefrag](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104181025/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897426.aspx)

Comment: As I remember from my past quick lookup, PageDefrag doesn't work with Windows 10.

Comment: It seems more a problem with [x64](https://forum.sysinternals.com/pagedfrg-and-windows-7_topic22501.html) rather than a specific Windows version.

Comment: At the time of writing, PageDefrag link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to disable your pagefile, I.e. no pagefile, reboot and do a full defrag, then reinitilize your pagefile, it should no longer be fragmented, but with enough RAM, as before shouldn't need one, I have 8Mb and notice no slowdown

Answer (score 0):

Wow, how did you set 8Mb? Only one megabyte? How?

The less it allows is 16MiB (sixteen megabytes) for pagefile.

There is another trick, without having pagefile at all, use a separate NTFS partition, create with NOTEPAD an empty file called 'pagefile.sys' (or any other name you wish) on whatever folder you wish and using MKLINK create a file "pagefile.sys" with size 'zero' on the root of the system partition that links to the other NTFS partition file, then activate pagefile on system partition.

That way windows will see there is a pagefile.sys on root of system partition, but it will be really stored on another partition & folder.

Same trick also works for "swapfile.sys"... but not sure if can be used with "hiberfil.sys" i always preffer to have hibernation off.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10:
Puran Defrag (free version) is the most useful I have found, so far, re boot-time defrag.
Still can't get MFT below 2 fragments. Maybe some Windows reset/repair job can fix that, Idk yet...

Mostly, it seems, my problems stem from a fragmented, and more and more fragmented, Registry. Full backup of, then restoring of, the registry is the only idea makes sense to me now - when all else fails.
ERUNT used to be the go to utility for that, but it doesn't work now.
This does tho https://www.tweaking.com/content/page/registry_backup.html. Of course, requires a restart to restore registry, but now Puran Defrag shows Registry as 1 - instead of 3, 4, 6 or whatever.